# i want to insert image name in db where to put sql query i m new to php

Tags: php

```
<?php include 'connection.php';?> 
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Multiple File Upload with PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" id="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload!" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "zip", "bmp");
$max_file_size = 1024*1000; //100 kb
$path = "uploads/"; // Upload directory
$count = 0;

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    // Loop $_FILES to exeicute all files
    foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $f => $name) {     
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 4) {
            continue; // Skip file if any error found
        }          

        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] == 0) {              
            if ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] > $max_file_size) {
                $message[] = "$name is too large!.";
                continue; // Skip large files
            }
            elseif( ! in_array(pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION), $valid_formats) ){
                $message[] = "$name is not a valid format";
                continue; // Skip invalid file formats
            }

            else{ // No error found! Move uploaded files 
                $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['files']['name'][$f], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$uniq_name = uniqid() . '.' .$ext;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["files"]["tmp_name"][$f], $path . $uniq_name);
               // $count++; // Number of successfully uploaded file
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: check this url  https://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-store-in-database-php-mysql/

Comment: i have already the source code of this tutorial...but still can't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your insert query inside the else statement when file successfully uploaded